# About the source of the and macro

Tags: clojure

I was browsing the source of clojure.core:

```
(defmacro and
  ([] true)
  ([x] x)
  ([x & next]
   `(let [and# ~x]
      (if and# (and ~@next) and#))))
```

Why not just

```
(defmacro and
  ([] true)
  ([x] x)
  ([x & next]
   `(if ~x (and ~@next) ~x)))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the argument `x` is a form, which might be any expression, that can be evaluated twice in `(if ~x (and ~@next) ~x))`. The `let`evaluates it once and uses the *value* `x#` thereafter.

So the actual code avoids the effects - the side effects in particular - of evaluating the arguments twice.

---

@amalloy points out that the second instance of form `x` in `(if ~x (and ~@next) ~x))` is evaluated only if the first instance evaluates false(y).

Comment: Well, it *is* an expression, not just "might" be. The "might" is that it might be evaluated twice (specifically, when it is falsey it will be evaluated twice).

Comment: @amalloy Yes. Your second point is fundamental. Whereas I knew formally that `if` does not evaluate its `then` and `else` arguments in advance, the idea that it suspends the animation of the forms hadn't forced itself home. I've tried to correct the answer without obscuring the point.